# Windows 2012 Command prompt not accepting a few commands

Tags: windows-server-2012, windows-command-prompt

I have recently installed Windows 2012.
Unable to use common commands previously used e.g. "ipconfig" "hostname" etc.
Have tried both Run as Administrator and non admin.

Comment: What's the error message you receive? Check your $PATH and compare with a working server.

Comment: @duenni the error i get is

C:\Users\Administrator>ipconfig
'ipconfig' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Path Dump

== working server ==
C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\VisualSVN Server\bin



== new 2012 server ==
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\Client SDK\ODBC\110\Tools\Binn\

Comment: And what do you get for `echo %systemroot%` ?

Comment: http://i64.tinypic.com/zu7pl.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `ipconfig` or other commands are not working, it is due to path variable missing in configuration.

Follow these steps to fix it:

1. Open the *Start-Menu* and  Right click on *‘Computer’* and click *‘Properties*’
2. Click ‘*Advanced System Settings’* then *‘Environmental Variables’* at the bottom of the screen
3. Check for *‘Path’* in the list. If it is present, Click *‘Edit’*
4. Go to the end of the text box and type the following (without quotes): `%systemroot%\system32`

3b. If it does not exist, create it with the *‘new’*  button,

4b. In the next window, enter the variable name as **Path**. Enter the variable path as, “;%systemroot%\system32”  (without quotes).

5. Click *ok* to close.

Now open a new cmd prompt and type ‘*ipconfig*‘ or any of the system commands and they should work fine!

Comment: Thanks @Overmind managed to get it solved but adding the full path at the end.

Comment: Glad it worked.